# How to increase PHP memory_limit in Debian Jessie?

Tags: php, memory-management, debian, memory-limit

I need to temporarily increase `memory_limit` on my Debian Jessie server. And no, I cannot make my script use less memory, as it is not my script and I really need to run it. Setting `memory_limit` and `suhosin.memory_limit` in `php.ini` does not have any effect.

Is there any other solution apart from recompiling PHP?

Comment: Very improbable that changing the limit has *no* effect. Did you restart the service after editing the file? What were the exact error messages before and after? What were the settings before and after? Why are you changing the global settings and not just for the script causing problems?

Answer (score 4):

Run `php --ini` on terminal to get the php.ini file for php-cli.

Also check `phpinfo()` for the php.ini file. You should edit these two files and restart apache `service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script running in CLI or HTTP? Are you sure if you changed settings in php.ini correctly?

Comment: HTTP. So I changed /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini .

Comment: Did you restart apache? Which memory value do you see if you create script with `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: Yes I did. No matter what value is in php.ini, phpinfo() always shows 128M .

Comment: Disable suhosin or look at http://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-memory-limit

Comment: Yes, I know this. Can you explain how I can disable suhosin when it is compiled into PHP (as I understand it is in Jessie)?

Comment: set suhosin.simulation = on as in http://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-simulation or try apt-get remove php5-suhosin

Comment: No luck. It seems Jessie disables this switch either. No php5-suhosin package in [Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/stable/php/).

Answer (score 0):

Really strange, I just changed my memory limit on Jessie, restarted apache, and phpinfo now shows the correct number.

Maybe your limit is set in a .htaccess file or via an ini_set() function?